# Why does lsqnonlin reshape its input argument?

Tags: matlab

The optimization function lsqnonlin appears to change the shape of `x`, the argument to the function being minimized, if `x` is a multidimensional matrix. Why does it do this and can I stop it?

The [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/matrix-arguments.html) says "When x0 is a matrix, solvers pass x as a matrix of the same size as x0 to ... the objective function." However, in the following example the size of x changes on subsequent iteration of lsqnonlin.

Function to minimize:

```
function y = myfun(X)
size(X)
y = [];
for k = 1:numel(X)
   y(k) = 2 * X(k) + 5;
end
end
```

Call to lsqnonlin:

```
x0 = rand(2,2,3);
x = lsqnonlin(@myfun,x0);
```

Displays:

```
ans =

     2     2     3

ans =

     2     6
```

etc.

Why is the shape of X changing?

Comment: Interesting. I've seen that `fminunc` has the same problem. In the help of `fminunc` we find: "x = fminunc(fun,x0) starts at the point x0 and attempts to find a local minimum x of the function described in fun. x0 can be a **scalar, vector, or matrix**". I guess lsqnonlin also just doesn't accept higher dimensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**:
This bug have been fixed in MATLAB R2015b.

---

By looking at the stack trace it appears that the dimension of the optimization variable `X` becomes wrong when the objective function is called by `finDiffEvalAndChkErr`, that in turn is called by `finitedifferences`. These are encrypted functions so there is not much to say. The only thing to do is to notice this to Mathworks.

The function `finitedifferences` behaves in this way because when it is called by `sfdnls` it receives: `X` in column array shape, and its true size as number of rows and number of colums, the latter being the product of the last dimensions of `X`.

I guess that the dimensions of `X` can be restored by a `reshape` inside `myfun`. Another possibility is to give to `lsqnonlin` the gradient of the objective function, so that the *clearly buggy* internal functions are no longer used.

Comment: I'm not concerned with the shape of y. My question is about the shape of X.

Comment: I'm sorry, I completely misunderstood your question. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: So It's a bug. Thanks for confirming!